# Show the sum is equal to a product of six primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

On a set of math challenges, one of them is to prove that $$145678+456781+567814+678145+781456+814567$$ is the product of six different primes.  This sounds like number theory to me, but I have no background in the subject, so I was wondering if anyone can indicate how the proof is supposed to go?

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar, I haven't tried anything because I really know nothing about number theory.  I was going to see how people answered it to find out whether I could follow the answer and do some more research from there.

Comment: I have shown my answer below. Please see that and Mark Bennet's advice on solving contest problems.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [here](http://metroplexmathcircle.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/amc_8_at_mmc.pdf),

> Write $145678=1\cdot 10^5+4\cdot 10^4+5\cdot 10^3+6\cdot 10^2+7\cdot 10+8$, and do the same for all other numbers. Each of the digits appears exactly once at each of the six place-value positions, giving the result of addition as
>   $$(1+4+5+6+7+8)\cdot(10^5+10^4+10^3+10^2+1)=\\
> 31\cdot 111\cdot1001=31\cdot3\cdot37\cdot11\cdot7\cdot13$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Have you noticed that each separate digit appears exactly once in each position. Try adding without carrying and see what happens.

[it took me less than a minute to write down the six primes - so you should give a bit more effort before expecting a solution - sometimes the process of solving it yourself is valuable]

Comment: Sorry, I noticed that pattern, but I wasn't sure  what to do with it.  Like I said, I have no exposure to number theory, so if that's what this is, I don't know the traditional techniques.

Comment: @Addem That isn't really number theory - if you notice a pattern in a problem, try doing something with it. It is number theory to know that $10^{p-1}\equiv 1$ mod $p$, so that if $p$ is a factor of $10^6-1=999,999$ so that $10^6\equiv 1$ mod $p$ then we have either $p|10-1, p|10^2-1, p|10^3-1$ or $p-1=6n$ so that $p=6n+1$. This reduces the work if you can't spot the prime factors. The factors $7$ and $13$ belong to $10^6$ so $\frac 17$ and $\frac 1{13}$ have a decimal expansion in which $6$ digits recur.